# Segmentaion Fault when enabling lightning gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

Tags: android

I am getting segmentation fault (signal 11) in android whenever i enable lightening i.e gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING). When i comment this line, i am able to view 3d image which i get after parsing .obj file. Here is the Code:

```
 public class GlRenderer implements Renderer {
    private square      square;     // the square
    private Context context;
    private float ambientMaterial[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
    private float diffuseMaterial[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    private float light_position[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f };
    private FloatBuffer ambientMaterialbfr;
    private FloatBuffer diffuseMaterialbfr;
    private FloatBuffer light_positionbfr;
    /** Constructor to set the handed over context */
    public GlRenderer(Context context) {
        Log.d("INFO","GlRenderer:Constructor");   
        this.context = context;
              // initialise the square
                this.square = new square();
            }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            //Log.d("INFO","GLRender:onDrawFrame");

            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();                      // reset the matrix to its default state





            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
           gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);



          //Commented By Rakesh
       // gl.glTranslatef(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // move 5 units INTO the screen

                                         // is the same as moving the camera 5 units away
                square.draw(gl);                        // Draw the triangle

            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
                Log.d("INFO","GLRender:onSurfaceChanged");
                if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
                    height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
                }

                 gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

                 float ratio = (float) width / height;
                // Log.d("INFO","Ratio is: "+ratio);
                 gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);        // set matrix to projection mode
                 gl.glLoadIdentity();                        // reset the matrix to its default state
                gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);  // apply the projection matrix

                //gl.glFrustumf(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar)

              // GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, ratio, 0.1f, 100.0f);

              // gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
             //gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix
            }

            @Override
            public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

                square.loadGLTexture(gl, this.context);


                Log.d("INFO","GLRender:onSurfaceCreated");

                     gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);    
                    //Enable Texture Mapping ( NEW )
                        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
                        gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.4f, .5f, 0.5f);    //Black Background

                        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
                        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
                        gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
                                //Really Nice Perspective Calculations
                 gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);




                //Lightning
                 Log.d("INFO","GLRender:onSurfaceChanged:Before Lighting");

                    ByteBuffer abb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ambientMaterial.length * 4 );
                    abb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                    ambientMaterialbfr = abb.asFloatBuffer();

                    ByteBuffer dbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(diffuseMaterial.length * 4 );
                    dbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                    diffuseMaterialbfr = dbb.asFloatBuffer();

                    ByteBuffer lbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(light_position.length * 4 );
                    lbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
                    light_positionbfr = lbb.asFloatBuffer();

                    ambientMaterialbfr = FloatBuffer.wrap(ambientMaterial);
                      diffuseMaterialbfr = FloatBuffer.wrap(diffuseMaterial);
                      light_positionbfr = FloatBuffer.wrap(light_position);



                      for (int j = 0; j < ambientMaterial.length; j++) {

                        ambientMaterialbfr.put(ambientMaterial[j]);

                    }



                    for (int j = 0; j < diffuseMaterial.length; j++) {

                        diffuseMaterialbfr.put(diffuseMaterial[j]);

                    }


                    for (int j = 0; j < light_position.length; j++) {

                        light_positionbfr.put(light_position[j]);

                    }

                    ambientMaterialbfr.position(0);
                    diffuseMaterialbfr.position(0);
                    light_positionbfr.position(0);

                     Log.d("INFO","Size of ambientMaterial:"+ambientMaterial.length);
                     Log.d("INFO","Size of diffuseMaterial:"+diffuseMaterial.length);
                     Log.d("INFO","Size of light_position:"+light_position.length);

                      gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, ambientMaterialbfr);
                      gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseMaterialbfr);
                     gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT1, GL10.GL_POSITION, light_positionbfr);

                     Log.d("INFO","GLRender:onSurfaceChanged:After glLightfv");
                    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING); 

                    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT1);

                     Log.d("INFO","GLRender:onSurfaceChanged:After COLOR_MATERIAL");
                      gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT, GL10.GL_AMBIENT,
                     ambientMaterialbfr); 
                     gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT,
                      GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseMaterialbfr);
                    gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT,
                            GL10.GL_POSITION, light_positionbfr);
                     Log.d("INFO","GLRender:onSurfaceChanged:After MATERIAL");





            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You pass that data to glMaterial, not to glColorPointer. See the [**glMaterial reference page (OpenGL ES).**](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glMaterial.xml)

I Hope it Helps